# The best way to publish new version to Azure app/services?

Tags: azure, publish

Say I have 1 azure app which calls 1 azure api service. Now I need to update both applications to a newer version, in the most extended scale, i.e. database not compatible, api has changes to existing method signatures that are not compatible to old version invocation either. I use visual studio's publish profile to directly update. The problem I've been facing is that during the publish process, although it's only a few seconds of time, there're still active end users doing things on the web app and making api calls. I've personally seen results in such situations which are unstable, unpredictable and the saved data might be simply corrupt data.
So is there a better way to achieve some sort of 'flash update' which causes absolutely no side effect to end users? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at a different deployment strategy. First update the database, maybe with accepting null values, deploy a new API next to the current one. Validate it. Switch the traffic from current to new. Same for the website. It is a blue green deployment strategy, requires some more effort but solves the downtime or errors. https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html

Answer (score 1):

For the web app, you should use the deployment slots, deploy your new version to a staging slot and once you are ready, it is a matter of pointing the site URL to the new slot. This doesn't take anytime at all.

For the database, I believe you should freeze updates, take a backup and let the users work in readonly mode, and once you finish all your DB migration and changes, point the application to the new database and that is it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, giving me a lot of inspirations too. thx.